# Parse input in java from mutiple line

Tags: java

I have got n lines of numbers , all containing equal number of numbers lets say m , how to store  them in 2d array

```
1 5 7 9  
2 3 4 6  
3 4 5 8
```

Note that here value of n and m is not given .

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new     InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {
    String line=br.readLine();
    String [] str =line.trim().split(" ");
    int n=str.length;
    columns=n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        matrix[rows][i]=Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
    }
        rows++;
    }
```

Runtime error is coming
  Runtime error time: 0.14 memory: 321088 signal:-1

Comment: please post the code you have already tried yourself to achieve this, then post any errors/problems you have with that code.

Comment: If you don't know the number of items and you already need to store it, you can use an implementation of `List`, like `ArrayList` to store, at least while you're loading the data. You can convert it to an array later with the `toArray` method.

Comment: What error. Show it!

Answer (score 2):

You can temporarily store everything into an `ArrayList`, then iterate over it at the end and create your 2D array:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader("C:/YourFile.txt");
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int rows=0, cols=0;
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String [] str = line.trim().split(" ");
    int n = str.length;
    cols = n;
    for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(str[i]));
    }
    ++rows;
}

// now create a 2D array and store everything into it
int[][] array = new array[rows][cols];
for (int i=0; i < rows; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j < cols; ++j) {
        array[i][j] = list.get(i*cols+j);
    }
}
```

Comment: its should be list.add(Integer.parseInt(str[i])                 still runtime error is coming

Comment: Good catch...I don't have access to a JVM at the moment ^ ^

Comment: while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);    // here null is printed
        String [] str = line.trim().split(" ");

Comment: What do you mean by your comment?

Comment: if i am printing line read by br , null is printed instead of line read

Comment: Try again with my updated code.  Just use a `BufferedReader` directly, and specify the full path to your input file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    List<List<Integer>> ints = new ArrayList<>();
    String d = "1 5 7 9  \n"
            + "2 3 4 6  \n"
            + "3 4 5 8  ";
    for (String line : d.split("\n")) {
        List<Integer> row = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String cell : line.split(" ")) {
            row.add(Integer.parseInt(cell));
        }
        ints.add(row);
    }
    System.out.println(ints);
```

Output:

```
[[1, 5, 7, 9], [2, 3, 4, 6], [3, 4, 5, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but I think using `System.in` in two objects (`Scanner` and `InputStreamReader`) causes issues, as characters may be consumed by the scanner before being read by the reader.

If you leave away the scanner, and just use `BufferedReader.ready()` in your while condition, it works (nearly the same code) :

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
while(br.ready())
{
    String line=br.readLine();
    String [] str =line.trim().split(" ");
    int n=str.length;
    columns=n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        matrix[rows][i]=Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
    }
    rows++;
}
```

You might prefer [Tichodroma's more elegent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29644731/parse-input-in-java-from-mutiple-line#answer-29644839).

Comment: I suggest an answer that is closer to the OP initial attempt, however I personally prefer [Tichodroma's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29644731/parse-input-in-java-from-mutiple-line#answer-29644839)